# "How's things?" or "How are things?"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, contractions, greetings

In a short interview where people were introducing themselves I saw something that grammatically sounds erroneous. Is the use of *How's things* instead of *How're things* a kind of expression or a simple mistake?

> David: Hi. I’m David.
>
> Rachel: Hi. I’m Rachel. Pleased to meet you.
>
> David: Likewise. **How's things?**
>
> Rachel: Great thanks. And You?

Comment: How's/Where's/Here's/There's + plural noun is exceedingly common in speech. How's your mom and dad? / Where's my keys? / Here's your keys. / There's two pizzas in the freezer.

Comment: Relevant:  [Use of “Here's” before a plural noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359055)

Comment: There's also multiple questions on "there's", e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/there-is-theres-vs-there-are); "there're" suffers from being hard to pronounce and distinguish, which is also the case with "here're", "where're", and other "'re" forms; even "how're" is trickier than "how's".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression, fairly common here in the Midwestern USA, at least; it is equivalent to "How are things going?" or "How are you?"

Answer (score 10):

I've tried running this through my head to hear what I actually say, and what I wind up with is either "how are things" or "how's everything", both of which agree in number.  However, I'd regard "how's things" as an acceptable alternative in informal speech, if it's generally used in your region.  In a more formal context (a job interview, for example), I would avoid any of these constructs in favor of "how are you".

Answer (score 4):

Some idioms do break the usual rules. They're called ill-formed idioms or extragrammatical idioms. *How's things* is one; it's in a colloquial register, in my opinion - you wouldn't use it in a scientific paper, for instance. *It's us* is a similar 'wrong agreement' idiom, widely accepted in almost every register. There are many extragrammatical idioms breaking various 'laws', for instance:

all of a sudden

by and large

curiouser and curiouser

dog eat dog

fight tooth and nail

for free

for short

it never rains but it pours

lead someone a merry dance

look daggers at someone

more fool you

swear blind

writ large

Comment: I wonder why "it never rains but it pours" ungrammatical.

Comment: The sense of 'but' here is 'except'. */? _It never rains except it pours_. (ie aiming for 'It never just rains a little – it always throws it down.') (It's not the illogical but grammatical 'It never rains – but it _does_ pour' sense.)