# Why I have heard people say There's two cars?

Tags: grammar

Why I have heard people say either `There's two cars` which I thought it should be `There are two cars`.

Or `'s` has some special meaning to it?

Comment: @Andrew: In actual fact, ***there's*** quite a few questions on this usage - *all* of which are probably duplicates. For example, [“There’s” or “There are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/), [There is (there's) vs.There are](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/), and [“There are so many” vs. “There is so many”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/).

Comment: Also see *[Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865)* .

Comment: 'There's the England team' might make most people happy. For conflicting reasons.