# "There is" and "there's" used before a plural word

Tags: grammatical-number, slang, there-is

I was just wondering how can you use "there **is**" followed by a word that is in plural, e.g

"There's cupcakes in the fridge"

and

"There is a couple of things we can do --"

Is it just slang?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You will likely find your answer in *["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854)*; also see *[Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865)*, *[“There are so many” vs. “There is so many”](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/9248/16052)*, or *[There is (there's) vs.There are](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155669/16052)*.

Comment: Sorry for a duplicate, I promise to search more in the future before asking a question. if someone can delete this question, then go ahead and delete it.

Comment: Don't feel bad; it happens to everyone. This question probably will be left up to provide a redirect, since it may show up when searching with different terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Existential "there"** is an unusual subject; it has no inherent number, but takes on the number of the displaced subject:

"There were some keys near the safe". (plural with "were")

"There was a nurse present". (singular with "was")

It’s comparable to the relative pronouns "which" and "who", which take on the number of their antecedent ("the guys who were talking" vs "the guy who was talking"). However, in informal style, especially in present tense declaratives with reduced "is", many speakers treat "there" as always singular: they say "There’s a few problems" instead of "There are a few problems". Prescriptivists disapprove, but the usage is too well established to be treated as an occasional slip.