# There is & There are

Tags: grammar, american-english

Why do we sometimes use "there is" for a plural form in our sentences? Example:
"There is some cars".
Is this true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["There is" and "there's" used before a plural word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294373/there-is-and-theres-used-before-a-plural-word) (and other linked threads) (see BillJ's and especially Barrie England's answers).

Comment: Because number agreement is not an important thing in English (no matter what your teachers tell you) and pronunciation **is** an important thing in English. [_There's_ is what English speakers say](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54754/15299) when they think their teacher isn't listening.