# "There are" or "there is"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

1. "There are Mary and Nat"
2. "There's Mary and Nat"

Which sentence is correct and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is (there's) vs.There are](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/there-is-theres-vs-there-are) // (1) is indisputably correct. (2) is used very often in conversation, where it must nowadays be classed as being acceptable. In more formal writing, (1) is the better choice.

Comment: yes, thank you!